# Java - Closing a ServerSocketChannel

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
 Selector socketSelector = SelectorProvider.provider().openSelector();
ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);
serverChannel.register(socketSelector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
serverChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(1331));

new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            serverChannel.close();

        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException ex) {
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Note: The code is not complete, it is only a test.

This code should open the connection port 1331, and after 5 seconds running should close the connection by releasing the port to use. However, if I use this line:

```
serverChannel.register(socketSelector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
```

the port is not released, only if I remove, and if I remove can not accept customers.

How can I find a way to release the port without having to close the application?

Answer (score 1):

`SelectableChannels` that are registered with a `Selector` have deferred closes that only take effect the next time `select()` is called. It's documented somewhere rather obscure in the Javadoc that I can never find when I need it. So you need to call `select()` with a short timeout, say five seconds, and do nothing if it returns zero. Or, do whatever housekeeping may arise.

Comment: Thanks. This caught me because I wanted to close a particular listening socket but reuse the Selector with others.  The approach I took was to call `SelectionKey.cancel()` to deregister from the selector, then call `Selector.wakeup()` so it would notice before calling `ServerSocketChannel.close()`.

Comment: @WilliamPrice That doesn't make sense. You should close and wakeup, in that order. The cancel is redundant.

Comment: You're right that [cancel is redundant on close](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/spi/AbstractSelectableChannel.html#implCloseChannel--), thanks.  What I really wanted to convey was that [wakeup()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Selector.html#wakeup--) appears to be a viable alternative to `select()` and also happens to be non-blocking.